# Unable to simulate location on Xcode Version 9.0.1 (9A1004)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode9

I'm working on a project where it's very often necessary to change the user's location, of course I included all the necessary data to simulate the location from the very beginning of the project. Today Xcode does not pretend to be a custom location, I decided to try to simulate one of the standard locations (for example San Francisco), but when I launch the application on a real device, my real location is displayed on the real device. I tried to run the application on the simulator, but got the same result. I did a clean project, rebooted the real device (iPhone 7), rebooted Xcode but it did not give results. I read a few topics, but they all relate to the fact that the developers did not include the simulation of the location in the scheme. How can I fix this problem? Thank you.

[image]

**Update**: I've updated Xcode, now I'm using Version 9.1 (9B55), but this did not fix this bug. Sometimes (once a week approximately), Xcode refuses to simulate even standard locations from the list (for example San Francisco). Although the menu above the consoles shows that the location simulates.
[image]

Info.plist contains

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Turn On Location Services to allow App to show you Events near you.</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Turn On Location Services to allow App to show you Events near you.</string>
    <key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Turn On Location Services to allow App to show you Events near you.</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Turn On Location Services to allow App to show you Events near you.</string>
```

**Update 1**: Xcode does not simulate the location only on a real device (iPhone 7), two weeks ago there was no such problem. When I call CLLocationManager to show an alert, this alert on the real device is not shown at all. I repeat, this problem does not always repeat, this can happen once a week, but no methods help to restore this possibility to a working state.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same problem and here's my work around.

You know the Location Services is not working when you don't see the arrow on status bar when you request location. So just turn Location Services off and on again. I guess this is a bug.

1. Go to Phone Settings > Location Services... then turn it off and on.
2. Xcode > Debug > Location Simulation
3. Simulator > Debug > Location > Custom Location (this will take what you set from step 2.)

You should see the arrow on status bar when you request location. If not... try the steps again.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of everything ... Warning! , read this (from apple):

> You are required to include the **NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription** and **NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUsageDescription** keys in your app's Info.plist file. (If your app supports iOS 10 and earlier, the **NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription** key is also required.) If those keys are not present, authorization requests fail immediately.

Anyway, i just suggest make a simple test.

- Make sure that you set **Allow Location Simulation** on the **Run Scheme**  for your Debug Build Configuration on your target-
- Run your App, switch to the Map app on simulator (is is the rfirst time you use, make sure you accept  allow location dialog). -
- Change the location on the location icon on Xcode (see below), and check that the map move to that location-

[image: Xcode 9]

- If everything is ok, the map app must show selected location

[image]

If your app is not able to follow same behaviour, maybe you are missing something. Further reading:

[About Location Services and Maps](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497)

[CoreLocation Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation)

Cheers.

Comment: all the necessary keys in info.plist are, I indicated this, that I have been working on the project in this mode for more than 6 months, and only today Xcode can not simulate the location.

Comment: Xcode has a bug that it can't simulate your custom location when adding via gpx file. I filed a bug about that. It is fixed in latest beta.